# Google Code SVN + Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4, repository, google-code

For a new project created on Google Code, how to set it up with a new project in Xcode 4.0 ?

I have created the project on Google and in Xcode. Now that I add a svn repository in Xcode, it shows

`Unable to find revisions`

and there is this error on import:

> Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) on
>   response to OPTIONS request